# react-native-table-component importing Json data to table

Tags: json, react-native, react-native-table-component

Im trying to import some information from a Json-file to a table from react-native-table-component, I've tried to import it to a ListView and that works but i want a nicer looking table for my data. First my table have the data at the top, numbers 1-6 and then in the fetchWorkOrder() function im trying to change the rows into the data from the Json file. But whatever i try i always end up with undefined objects in the table.

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
tableHead: [ 'Art', 'Prod', 'Hämtas', 'Lämnas', 'Mängd', 'Status'],
tableData: [
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
]
}
}

componentDidMount(){
this.fetchWorkOrder();
//this.renderTable(); 
}

//https://gitlab.hiqkna.se/bth/bth-007-001/raw/master/workOrder.json
fetchWorkOrder(){
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Digy95/Json-files/master/workOrder5.json")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((response) => {
  this.setState({
    dataSource: response.workOrder1,
    tableData: [
        ['1', '2', `${response.workOrder1.articleNumber}`, '4', '5', '6'],
        ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
    ]
  });
});
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all the article numbers from the workOrder1? It's an array of objects, that's why you can't access directly the property workOrder1.articleNumber

Comment: Yes im trying to get all the information from workOrder1 out. Any ideas?

Comment: `dataSource: response.workOrder1` is already an array of objects from the workOrder1 :)